Fixing Semi-Auto Classificaton Plugin
Recently I did analysis with SCP and I notice it can change the system processing ram so I curiously changed that hopefully the program will process data faster. But it was a mistake I guess because now the program keep lagging and using much memory, I tried to change it but it always fail and I tried to reinstall the plugin and it fails too.
Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?
